# How do I call images in a subdirectory? Rails 4 app breaks when I push to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app that performs fine in development but as soon I as I push to production it breaks. It was working fine until I added a `/gifs` subdirectory to the `/images` directory.

I'm pulling a random gif in the directory and displaying it.

```
<%= image_tag "assets/gifs/#{rand(10)}.gif" %>
```

I've also tried

```
<%= image_tag "gifs/#{rand(10)}.gif" %>
```

and

```
<%= asset_url("gifs/#{rand(10)}.gif") %>
```

But nothing is working. How should I structure this?

Comment: Just try this once:Try clearing out your asset cache: rake assets:clean && rake tmp:cache:clear
Try putting the env setting first: RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/subdirectory rake assets:precompile

Comment: so what files do you actually have in this `gifs` folder?

Comment: Nine gifs. 1.gif, 2.gif, 3.gif, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried /assets?  Like this:

```
<%= image_tag "/assets/gifs/#{rand(10)}.gif" %>
```

I would start without the interpolation just to make sure you can see the image and then add the variable.

EDIT: Sorry for the quick shot, I have it like this in mine and thought that might fix it.  I think what you actually need is to tell your config/environments/production.rb that you want to precompile those folders also... in development, it will happily include everything for you, but in production, it needs to be more selective and rigid (there are various explanations for that elsewhere).

Try this:
open config/

look for this line: config.assets.precompile  and add your subfolder to it.

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'gifs/*.gif']
```

If you decided to organize your other assets into controller-related subfolders (I like that), you need to add those here too:  (example: local, resources, projects, shared subfolders)

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'local/*.css', 'resources/*.js', 'projects/*.js', 'shared/*.js', 'ui/*.js', 'admin.a    pp.js', 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js', 'date-picker.js', 'date_extras.js', 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @reknirt, I updated my previous comment to include formatted config changes that I think will fix this for you.  Just making sure you saw them.